# Resharper suggestion box no longer appears

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I recently reset my settings for visual studio and then applied visual studio integration scheme for resharper.

Originally if  I moved the caret to a code which contained an error or a warning etc ( e.g. name does not match resharper rule ), a icon used to appear on the left side of the line with the suggestions.

Now that icon does not appear automatically and i need to press alt+enter to force it to appear.

Any idea how i can reset this functionality without reinstalling resharper?

EDIT:
this is the menu i am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Do you have enabled code analysis (ReSharper->Options->Code Inspection->Settings->Enable code analysis)?

Comment: @thersch I can confirm that it is enabled

Comment: Why not simply reinstall ReSharper? Your (custom) settings will not be reset.

Comment: @hmemcpy that is precisely what i will do tomorrow. i just wanted to know the reason before reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalling resharper fixed the issue.